# How do I get rid of browser provided option to save credentials

Tags: selenium-webdriver

After the selenium script logins, browser gives an option to store credentials. Is there a way in Webdriver to get rid of that option?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: @arm Which browser are you using?

Comment: @JeffC, Yes, thank you. I will remember that.

Comment: @Dev, Thank you for your help.  I will be using IE, FF and Chrome.  Can I use the following code for other browsers too?

Comment: @arm My Answer for your Question is specifically for Google Chrome browser. For IE & FF you need to write code in similar lines. Please Accept the Answer as a solution if that catered to your Question with Chrome browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start Chrome disabling Password Manager you need to:

1. Download and use the latest chrome driver from [this link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).
2. Add the preferences & options to your code as follows:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumUtilities\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
   Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
   prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
   prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
   driver.get("http:\\gmail.com");
   ```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the save password option, you need to add the below preferences before initializing the webdriver.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```